# Calling a hook function every time an Exception is raised

Tags: python, exception

Let's say I want to be able to log to file every time any exception is raised, anywhere in my program. I don't want to modify any existing code.

Of course, this could be generalized to being able to insert a hook every time an exception is raised.

Would the following code be considered safe for doing such a thing?

```
class MyException(Exception):

    def my_hook(self):
        print('---> my_hook() was called');

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global BackupException;
        self.my_hook();
        return BackupException.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs);


def main():
    global BackupException;
    global Exception;

    BackupException = Exception;
    Exception = MyException;

    raise Exception('Contrived Exception');


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main();
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you're trying to accomplish with this.  Why try to write messages on ALL exceptions?

Comment: This is mainly academic curiosity ... it would be nice to visually see exception handling happening in real time, for all the code that's being run.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to log *uncaught* exceptions, just use [sys.excepthook](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook).

I'm not sure I see the value of logging *all* raised exceptions, since lots of libraries will raise/catch exceptions internally for things you probably won't care about.

Comment: Note that this is not sufficient with Threads: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9929970/321973

Answer (score 10):

Your code as far as I can tell would not work.

1. `__init__` has to return None and you are trying to return an instance of backup exception. In general if you would like to change what instance is returned when instantiating a class you should override `__new__`.
2. Unfortunately you can't change any of the attributes on the `Exception` class. If that was an option you could have changed `Exception.__new__` and placed your hook there.
3. the "`global Exception`" trick will only work for code in the current module. `Exception` is a builtin and if you really want to change it globally you need to `import __builtin__; __builtin__.Exception = MyException`
4. Even if you changed `__builtin__.Exception` it will only affect future uses of `Exception`, subclasses that have already been defined will use the original Exception class and will be unaffected by your changes. You could loop over `Exception.__subclasses__` and change the `__bases__` for each one of them to insert your `Exception` subclass there.
5. There are subclasses of `Exception` that are also built-in types that you also cannot modify, although I'm not sure you would want to hook any of them (think `StopIterration`).

I think that the only decent way to do what you want is to patch the Python sources.

Comment: You make your idea sound like it's a bad thing! This is awesome.

Comment: Since the OP's comment is that this is for academic curiosity, patching the Python source code could be a really fun and educational way to see what's going on at great granularity.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to do this because some framework is swallowing an exception and I need to find out where the exception is coming from. Patching CPython in my case would be an absolute nightmare.

Answer (score 7):

This code will not affect any exception classes that were created before the start of `main`, and most of the exceptions that happen will be of such kinds (`KeyError`, `AttributeError`, and so forth). And you can't really affect those "built-in exceptions" in the most important sense -- if anywhere in your code is e.g. a 1/0, the *real* ZeroDivisionError will be raised (by Python's own internals), *not* whatever else you may have bound to that exceptions' name.

So, I don't think your code can do what you want (despite all the semicolons, it's still supposed to be Python, right?) -- it could be done by patching the C sources for the Python runtime, essentially (e.g. by providing a hook potentially caught on *any* exception even if it's later caught) -- such a hook currently does not exist because the use cases for it would be pretty rare (for example, a `StopIteration` is always raised at the normal end of every `for` loop -- and caught, too; why on Earth would one want to trace *that*, and the many other routine uses of caught exceptions in the Python internals and standard library?!).

Comment: This was mainly an exercise in academic curiosity. Given the highly dynamic nature of Python, I figured this would be easy to do.

Comment: Not sure what "highly dynamic" means -- it certainly seems less dynamic than Common Lisp, which is (a) typically implemented in itself, and (b) has restartable conditions, at least one of which seems necessary to implement such a thing without special support for it.

Answer (score -8):

Download [pypy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/) and instrument it.

Comment: how did this realted to the question?

Comment: If you want to see exception handling, you can get the PyPy implementation of Python.  Modify the code for exception handling and "visually see exception handling happening in real time, for all the code that's being run".

Comment: how could this be a solution ??