# Log exception with traceback in Python

Tags: python, exception, logging, error-handling, python-logging

How can I log my Python exceptions?

```
try:
    do_something()
except:
    # How can I log my exception here, complete with its traceback?
```

Answer (score 330, accepted):

Use [`logging.exception`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.exception) from within the `except:` handler/block to log the current exception along with the trace information, prepended with a message.

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = '/tmp/logging_example.out'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME, level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')

try:
    run_my_stuff()
except:
    logging.exception('Got exception on main handler')
    raise
```

Now looking at the log file, `/tmp/logging_example.out`:

```
DEBUG:root:This message should go to the log file
ERROR:root:Got exception on main handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/teste.py", line 9, in <module>
    run_my_stuff()
NameError: name 'run_my_stuff' is not defined
```

Comment: Looked over the django code for this, and I'm assuming the answer is no, but is there a way to limit the traceback to a certain amount of either characters or depth? The problem is that for large tracebacks, it takes pretty long.

Comment: Note that if you define a logger with `logger = logging.getLogger('yourlogger')`you have to write `logger.exception('...')`to have this working...

Comment: Can we modify this so that the message is printed with log level INFO?

Comment: Note that for certain external apps, such as Azure insight, the trackback is not stored in the logs. It is then necessary to pass them explicitly to the message string as show below.

Comment: I had always thought `logging.exception(...)` (or `logger.exception(...)` if so configured) would do it. But I've become a bit confused with this method `exception` in the context of an exception hook handler: it doesn't seem to print out the traceback in this context.  Beginning to suspect your calling code has to be in an `except` block for this to work.

Comment: Won't it cause the application to crash as we are raising exception again inside except. What if we want to just log the traceback but not cause the application to fail?

Comment: Just saying, it might be more appropriate to use `except Exception: ...`, using `except` will catch BaseExceptions, which include exceptions from the Exception class, but also includes things like `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Answer (score 240):

Use `exc_info` options may be better, remains warning or error title:

```
try:
    # coode in here
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e, exc_info=True)
```

Comment: I can never remember what the `exc_info=` kwarg is called; thanks!

Comment: This is identical to logging.exception, with the exception that the type is redundantly logged twice. Just use logging.exception unless you want a level other than error.

Comment: @Wyrmwood it's not identical as you have to supply a message to `logging.exception`

Comment: Using `logging.error`, one can avoid giving awkward messages like `''` or `' '` to `logging.exception`.

Comment: `logging.exception` is calling `logging.error` so theoretically this could be written as `logging.exception(e)` and one can still avoid passing in a message.

Answer (score 79):

My job recently tasked me with logging all the tracebacks/exceptions from our application. I tried numerous techniques that others had posted online such as the one above but settled on a different approach. Overriding `traceback.print_exception`.

I have a write up at [http://www.bbarrows.com/](http://www.bbarrows.com/blog/2012/09/24/implementing-exception-logging-in-python/) That would be much easier to read but Ill paste it in here as well.

When tasked with logging all the exceptions that our software might encounter in the wild I tried a number of different techniques to log our python exception tracebacks. At first I thought that the python system exception hook, sys.excepthook would be the perfect place to insert the logging code. I was trying something similar to:

```
import traceback
import StringIO
import logging
import os, sys

def my_excepthook(excType, excValue, traceback, logger=logger):
    logger.error("Logging an uncaught exception",
                 exc_info=(excType, excValue, traceback))

sys.excepthook = my_excepthook
```

This worked for the main thread but I soon found that the my sys.excepthook would not exist across any new threads my process started. This is a huge issue because most everything happens in threads in this project.

After googling and reading plenty of documentation the most helpful information I found was from the Python Issue tracker.

The first post on the thread shows a working example of the `sys.excepthook` NOT persisting across threads (as shown below). Apparently this is expected behavior.

```
import sys, threading

def log_exception(*args):
    print 'got exception %s' % (args,)
sys.excepthook = log_exception

def foo():
    a = 1 / 0

threading.Thread(target=foo).start()
```

The messages on this Python Issue thread really result in 2 suggested hacks. Either subclass `Thread` and wrap the run method in our own try except block in order to catch and log exceptions or monkey patch `threading.Thread.run` to run in your own try except block and log the exceptions.

The first method of subclassing `Thread` seems to me to be less elegant in your code as you would have to import and use your custom `Thread` class EVERYWHERE you wanted to have a logging thread. This ended up being a hassle because I had to search our entire code base and replace all normal `Threads` with this custom `Thread`. However, it was clear as to what this `Thread` was doing and would be easier for someone to diagnose and debug if something went wrong with the custom logging code. A custome logging thread might look like this:

```
class TracebackLoggingThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        try:
            super(TracebackLoggingThread, self).run()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except Exception, e:
            logger = logging.getLogger('')
            logger.exception("Logging an uncaught exception")
```

The second method of monkey patching `threading.Thread.run` is nice because I could just run it once right after `__main__` and instrument my logging code in all exceptions. Monkey patching can be annoying to debug though as it changes the expected functionality of something. The suggested patch from the Python Issue tracker was:

```
def installThreadExcepthook():
    """
    Workaround for sys.excepthook thread bug
    From
http://spyced.blogspot.com/2007/06/workaround-for-sysexcepthook-bug.html

(https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=105470&aid=1230540&group_id=5470).
    Call once from __main__ before creating any threads.
    If using psyco, call psyco.cannotcompile(threading.Thread.run)
    since this replaces a new-style class method.
    """
    init_old = threading.Thread.__init__
    def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        init_old(self, *args, **kwargs)
        run_old = self.run
        def run_with_except_hook(*args, **kw):
            try:
                run_old(*args, **kw)
            except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                raise
            except:
                sys.excepthook(*sys.exc_info())
        self.run = run_with_except_hook
    threading.Thread.__init__ = init
```

It was not until I started testing my exception logging I realized that I was going about it all wrong.

To test I had placed a

```
raise Exception("Test")
```

somewhere in my code. However, wrapping a a method that called this method was a try except block that printed out the traceback and swallowed the exception. This was very frustrating because I saw the traceback bring printed to STDOUT but not being logged. It was I then decided that a much easier method of logging the tracebacks was just to monkey patch the method that all python code uses to print the tracebacks themselves, traceback.print_exception.
I ended up with something similar to the following:

```
def add_custom_print_exception():
    old_print_exception = traceback.print_exception
    def custom_print_exception(etype, value, tb, limit=None, file=None):
        tb_output = StringIO.StringIO()
        traceback.print_tb(tb, limit, tb_output)
        logger = logging.getLogger('customLogger')
        logger.error(tb_output.getvalue())
        tb_output.close()
        old_print_exception(etype, value, tb, limit=None, file=None)
    traceback.print_exception = custom_print_exception
```

This code writes the traceback to a String Buffer and logs it to logging ERROR. I have a custom logging handler set up the 'customLogger' logger which takes the ERROR level logs and send them home for analysis.

Comment: Quite an interesting approach. One question - `add_custom_print_exception` doesn't appear to be on the site you linked to, and instead there's some quite different final code there. Which one would you say is better / more final and why? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, great answer!

Comment: There is a cut and paste typo.  on the delegated call to old_print_exception, limit and file should be passed limit and file, not None -- old_print_exception(etype, value, tb, limit, file)

Comment: For your last code block, rather than initializing a StringIO and printing the exception to it, you can just call `logger.error(traceback.format_tb())` (or format_exc() if you want the exception info too).

Comment: Your shared link is not working now. I am also not able to log the traceback using above method. I called `raise Exception` in code, and before the I called the method you defined. Nothing is happening. @Brad and @Christian

Comment: It looks like that the problem causing the exceptions raised from forked threads has been resolved in Python 3.8. Have a look at this [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue1230540)

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20181005170343/http://www.bbarrows.com/blog/2012/09/24/implementing-exception-logging-in-python

Answer (score 18):

You can log all uncaught exceptions on the main thread by assigning a handler to [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook), perhaps using the [`exc_info` parameter of Python's logging functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug):

```
import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/foobar.log')

def exception_hook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    logging.error(
        "Uncaught exception",
        exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
    )

sys.excepthook = exception_hook

raise Exception('Boom')
```

If your program uses threads, however, then note that threads created using [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) will *not* trigger `sys.excepthook` when an uncaught exception occurs inside them, as noted in [Issue 1230540](http://bugs.python.org/issue1230540) on Python's issue tracker. Some hacks have been suggested there to work around this limitation, like monkey-patching `Thread.__init__` to overwrite `self.run` with an alternative `run` method that wraps the original in a `try` block and calls `sys.excepthook` from inside the `except` block. Alternatively, you could just manually wrap the entry point for each of your threads in `try`/`except` yourself.

Comment: thanks for this, much more elegant than wrapping everything in my `main()` function with a `try: except`

Answer (score 12):

You can get the traceback using a logger, at any level (DEBUG, INFO, ...). Note that using `logging.exception`, the level is ERROR.

```py
# test_app.py
import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level="DEBUG")

def do_something():
    raise ValueError(":(")

try:
    do_something()
except Exception:
    logging.debug("Something went wrong", exc_info=sys.exc_info())
```

```
DEBUG:root:Something went wrong
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_app.py", line 10, in <module>
    do_something()
  File "test_app.py", line 7, in do_something
    raise ValueError(":(")
ValueError: :(
```

**EDIT:**

This works too (using python 3.6)

```py
logging.debug("Something went wrong", exc_info=True)
```

Answer (score 11):

What I was looking for:

```
import sys
import traceback

exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
traceback_in_var = traceback.format_tb(exc_traceback)
```

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

Answer (score 3):

Uncaught exception messages go to STDERR, so instead of implementing your logging in Python itself you could send STDERR to a file using whatever shell you're using to run your Python script. In a Bash script, you can do this with output redirection, as [described in the BASH guide](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).

#### Examples

Append errors to file, other output to the terminal:

```
./test.py 2>> mylog.log
```

Overwrite file with interleaved STDOUT and STDERR output:

```
./test.py &> mylog.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version that uses sys.excepthook

```
import traceback
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger()

def handle_excepthook(type, message, stack):
     logger.error(f'An unhandled exception occured: {message}. Traceback: {traceback.format_tb(stack)}')

sys.excepthook = handle_excepthook
```

Comment: How about using `{traceback.format_exc()}` instead of `{traceback.format_tb(stack)}`?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it.

```
try:
    do_something()
except:
    # How can I log my exception here, complete with its traceback?
    import traceback
    traceback.format_exc() # this will print a complete trace to stout.
```

Comment: also, I usually use `except Exception as e:` so I can print `e` if I don't want the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not as stylish, but easier:

```
#!/bin/bash
log="/var/log/yourlog"
/path/to/your/script.py 2>&1 | (while read; do echo "$REPLY" >> $log; done)
```

Answer (score 0):

To key off of others that may be getting lost in here, the way that works best with capturing it in logs is to use the `traceback.format_exc()` call and then split this string for each line in order to capture in the generated log file:

```
import logging
import sys
import traceback

try:
  ...
except Exception as ex:
  # could be done differently, just showing you can split it apart to capture everything individually
  ex_t = type(ex).__name__
  err = str(ex)
  err_msg = f'[{ex_t}] - {err}'
  logging.error(err_msg)

  # go through the trackback lines and individually add those to the log as an error
  for l in traceback.format_exc().splitlines():
    logging.error(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason simply using `log.exception(exc)` didn't work for me and I had to manually build the `exc_info` param as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24864888/4249857).

```
log.exception(exc, exc_info=(type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__))
```

Answer (score -3):

Heres a simple example taken from the [python 2.6 documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html):

```
import logging
LOG_FILENAME = '/tmp/logging_example.out'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG,)

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```

Comment: The question was how to log the traceback