# How do I log an exception object with traceback in Python 3

Tags: python, exception, logging, python-3.x

How can I log an exception object with its traceback in Python 3, using the standard [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module?

Note that the exception in question isn't necessarily the one currently being handled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logger objects accept an `exc_info` argument to include exception information (including traceback), which is expected to be a tuple containing the exception's class, the exception itself and the exception's traceback. The trickiest part is to get hold of the traceback, but it turns out that since Python 3.0, [exceptions have a `__traceback__` attribute](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3109/):

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
exc_info = (type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__)
logger.error('Exception occurred', exc_info=exc_info)
```

Comment: For Python 2.7 you can use [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) to get the traceback of the exception currently being handled.

Comment: @LukasGraf I know, but this question deals with general exception objects.

Comment: You can simply use: `logger.error('Exception occurred', exc_info=exc)`. Python itself will [extract exception type/traceback info](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1rc2/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1513).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't know if I'm contributing in the slightest by doing this, but I did find this resource that I thought pertinent to your question and I hope useful.

http://www.alexconrad.org/2013/02/loggingexception.html

The gist of it being, if you place logging.exception() inside of an except block, then you can log all of your errors.

Comment: The problem is it's not inside an exception handler.