# How to correctly troubleshoot python programs when exported with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, windows, exe, pyinstaller

I recently created a Python program and I managed to pack it into an exe by using PyInstaller.

The problem is the exe it produced generates a window that disappears so fast I cant read whats in it.

I have found no way to keep that window open:

`-c` and `-w` PyIinstaller commands are not working, neither is `--debug all`: the window is still appearing, producing super-fast terminal text in it and then closing itself without giving me enough time to read what problem it encountered.

Is there a way I can make PyInstaller exes produce a logfile of what happens when I run them?
Do you have any other suggestion on what can I do to understand why my program crashes, or to keep its window opened up so I can read what is in it?
Thanks for your interest :)

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting your code is nothing to do with Pyinstaller. You can use python [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) and redirect the console output to a text file. There is a good example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508467/log-exception-with-traceback).

Also, according to [this](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#getting-python-s-verbose-imports), if you have problem with importing your modules and needs more info you can use verbose mode, `-v` flag to print more info about the state of importing modules by Pyinstaller.

> You can also pass a `-v` (verbose imports) flag to the embedded Python
>   interpreter (see Giving Run-time Python Options above). This can be
>   extremely useful. It can be informative even with apps that are
>   apparently working, to make sure that they are getting all imports
>   from the bundle, and not leaking out to the local installed Python.

For your last question if you need to use a JSON string you can use a dictionary type with Python then use `json` module (`json.dumps`) to convert your `dict` to a valid JSON string. You can find more info in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745519/converting-dictionary-to-json-in-python).