# Python Traceback Errors - write to a text file

Tags: python, error-handling, traceback

I have written a script in Python. It has a GUI which I intend to distribute to my colleagues.
If when they run it and encounter a bug, is there a way to have these errors be written to a text file so I can know what the bug was?
In Jupyter notebook whenever I encounter a bug in my script, it shows as Traceback error. I want to see that kind of information in the text file whenever someone finds a bug.

Thank you

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1508761/7416198

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
import time
import os
import sys

def logger(logfile, bolus):
# Takes two inputs - logfile (path to desired file), and data to be written
# Writes "Y-M-D|H:M:S, bolus\n"
    f = open(logfile, 'a+')
    currentdate = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d|%H:%M:%S')
    f.write(currentdate + ',' + data +'\n')
    f.close()
```

Comment: Python supports filehandler for logging exceptions in a file. Why can't we use that instead?

Comment: Probably a better solution - I'm pretty new myself and this is what I use for debugging ‍♂️