# how to log all errors in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-logging

I want to save **ALL ERRORS** into a file which means the errors outside an exception, also get in the log file.

for example import some module and in the begining of a script, set it to save the errors; something like this:

```
import blob
blob.save_errors(filename)

try:
  lst = ['a']
  print(lst[2]) # save this Error
except:
  pass

print(2/0) # also save this error
```

Comment: Like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508467/log-exception-with-traceback-in-python

Comment: is only save the errors in exception block and should set it manual.

Comment: [Logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) is a good place to start. It's built into standard library.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy automatic way to process all the exception, it contradict with exception handling idea.

One of solutions: we can log all uncatched exceptions like this way:

```py
import sys
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
logger.addHandler(handler)

def handle_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    if issubclass(exc_type, KeyboardInterrupt):
        sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
    else:
        logger.critical("Exception occured:", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))

sys.excepthook = handle_exception

# Just to test
if __name__ == "__main__":
    raise Exception("Something happend!")
```

And to log all handled exception we need to all logging in `except` block:

```py
try:
    ...
except:
    logger.error("Exception occured:", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))
    ...
```

Other way to deal with exception is to handle them in top-level function. All non-handled exceptions from downstream functions will be processed in top-level `except` block:

```py
def my_main_func():
    try:
        run_my_application_logic()
    except:
        # Logging
        logger.error("Exception occured:", exc_info=(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))

def run_my_application_logic():
    first_step_of_app()
    second_step_of_app()
    third_step_of_app()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_main_func()
```

Comment: well thanks, but the first solution doesn't save worl actually, just prints the error same as before (I want to save the errors in a file)

Comment: @DANIEL1475
`looger` can write log to file. You just need to properly configure logger. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386698/how-to-write-to-a-file-using-the-logging-python-module