# Dump All Python Interpreter Errors into a Log?

Tags: python, linux

Is it possible to dump all errors reported by the Python Interpreter into a log stored as say `/var/log/python.log` regardless of what script/command caused them? What would be the best way to do this if it's possible?

Comment: This should help: [Calling a hook function every time an Exception is raised](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029318/calling-a-hook-function-every-time-an-exception-is-raised)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, admittedly redirecting stderr may not be the best answer. So another solution would be using `sys.excepthook`.

Below is an example of it being used.

```
import sys
import logging
import traceback

LOGFILE = '/var/log/python.log'

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    logging.critical(''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb)))
    logging.critical('{0}: {1}'.format(ex_cls, ex))

def main():
    raise Exception


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        filename=LOGFILE,
        filemode='w')

    sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

    main()
```

Unlike redirecting stderr it will only log the errors from the interpreter and not anything else the script outputs to std*.

Look at [this link](http://blog.tplus1.com/blog/2012/08/05/python-log-uncaught-exceptions-with-sys-excepthook/) for more details.

Comment: You should have edited your answer with the further info rather than posting a new one.

Comment: Sorry, I thought as they were two different solutions they should be two different answers.

Comment: No worries, I tend to stick to the one answer per user mantra, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect stderr.

`python script.py 2> /var/log/python.log`

Comment: That would also redirect anything the script outputs to stderr, so it's not really an answer to the question.