# Python: catching error + printing to file

Tags: python, error-handling

I wonder if there is a way to capture any (and all) type of error that crashes the script, but potentially without using `try` to catch a specific exception.

I have a webdriver script that does a lot of stuff, like clicks on links, sends keys and so on, but I cannot predict where it will crash. I want to run a series of tests in sequence and print results into a file - including any errors/crashes:
Eg.

```
Test01 - Success!   
Test02 - NameError: name 'driver' is not defined !ERROR!
Test03 - Success!
```

and so on.

So that at the end I can just open the text file and check which tests need to be fixed and re-run.

Now I've been using `try/exception` with smaller blocks of code, but it seems to me that I would have to somehow include the whole script within `try/catch/exception` to get what I want.

Is there a better way to catch any type of error that is displayed after a script crashes, like on the image below:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a hook function every time an Exception is raised](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029318/calling-a-hook-function-every-time-an-exception-is-raised)

Comment: @acdr I don't know how to do what Ken suggested in the post, ie. using the sys.excepthook, so I'm not sure if that question answers mine...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a plain `except` to catch any and all exceptions, like so:

```
try:
    some code here
except:
    print 'whoops, something went wrong'
```

However this doesn't give you any information about the exception, so you probably don't want to do that.

You can also catch the very broad `Exception`, like so:

```
try:
    some code here
except Exception as ex:
    print 'oops, caught this error: %s' % ex
```

This is a better method as it tells you what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Should I then put the whole script within try / exception and indent the whole script?

Comment: @Alichino that would work, however you might find that it catches more errors than you want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the trick you are looking for is redirecting the stderr to a file or stdout.

Python when having the exception will write the exception to stderr .
simply you need to redirect stderr to the same output file you have when running the python program

like this

> python file.py &> outputfile

Comment: When I do that in ipython, the file is not created. In normal command line it says to me: "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571090/ipython-redirecting-output-of-a-python-script-to-a-file-like-bash. it will show you code you can use to redirect the output in iPython. So use that code and redirect both stderr and stdout to same file

Comment: That looks good, but I think it's too much messing about... :) I think I'll just print Test_Number: at the beginning, then just before driver.quit() I'll append with SUCCESS!, so that when any test crashes before reaching that line, I'll only see Test Number: and I'll know something went wrong. But without knowing what exactly.

Comment: Honestly the easiest way is to wrap the code with try except like @John Gordon said. that is the least amount of work and the more correct solution (my solution is hacky based on your requirement of not using try)